# Creating text field in yii

Tags: php, yii

I need help. I have page with 4 combo boxes. 
Now, I need to make on same page one extra text field. I have two tables. Now the user can input into that text field something from table A, and that data suppose to go into table B. Table A and B are related.

well:

```
TABLE A:         
======== 
ID   Mark             
1    AA                
2    BB                
3    CC                
.    .                  
.    .                 

TABLE B:
========
A_ID
1
2
3
.
.
```

Comment: Please add more information so we can help you, like table columns, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The exact way you shall implement it depends on the relation type, i.e. `BELONGS_TO` or `HAS_MANY`?

A good way to start with is to create a new form model extending from `CFormModel`; here you can define attributes from both `A` and `B` models, along with any additional attributes you may need, and their relevant validation rules.

Your controller would then process the request separating the received data into separate target models for saving, updating, etc.

Let me know if you need any specific example or clarification.